# Difference between flex-fill and flex-grow-1 in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

What is the difference between `flex-fill` and `flex-grow-1` in Bootstrap 4+?

---

From the documentation,
[`flex-fill`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#fill) says:

> ### Fill
>
> Use the `.flex-fill` class on a series of sibling elements to force them into widths equal to their content (or equal widths if their content does not surpass their border-boxes) while taking up all available horizontal space.

Is `flex-fill` always intended to be only used on multiple sibling elements?

---

And [`flex-grow`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) says:

> ### Grow and shrink
>
> Use `.flex-grow-*` utilities to toggle a flex item’s ability to grow to fill available space.

---

In the following code snippet, both `flex-grow-1` and `flex-fill` seem to be doing the same thing which is to expand the element to take up any positive free space:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container border border-primary m-4 p-4">
    <h3>Default</h3>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <p class="border border-dark">This is some sample text.</p>
        <p><span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">1000</p>
    </div>
    <h3>With <code>.flex-fill</code></h3>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <p class="flex-fill border border-dark">This is some sample text.</p>
        <p><span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">1000</p>
    </div>
    <h3>With <code>.flex-grow-1</code></h3>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <p class="flex-grow-1 border border-dark">This is some sample text.</p>
        <p><span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">1000</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Are `flex-fill` and `flex-grow-1` always interchangeable? Or do they have specific use cases?

Comment: `flex-grow-1` will only make the sibling element that it is applied to grow. `flex-fill` is not sued on a sibling but the aprent element and applies it to all siblings. The difference is where you sue it and if you want to make a single element grow all all elements equally.

Comment: sue = use, aprent = parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**flex-grow-1** is only setting `flex-grow:1` therefore has no impact on flex-basis or flex-shrink.

whereas, **flex-fill** is setting...

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
```

or shorthand,

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
```

Effectively, `flex: 1 1 auto;` and `flex-grow: 1` are the same. This is because of the way flexbox works by default. Therefore, `flex-fill` and `flex-grow-1` can be used interchangeably.

However, Bootstrap created different classes for "grow" and "shrink" so that they can be used oppositionally within the same flex parent. Additionally, the other "grow" and "shrink" classes can used to switch between 1 and 0, whereas `flex-fill` is strictly for `flex-grow: 1`.